# How to remove white space in a p tag between header and content on Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So Wordpress has put all of my content in a p tag and it makes a white gap between it and the header. I can't figure out how to get rid of this gap! The image is classed as welcome.

I tried this but it still leaves a white gap

```
article p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.welcome {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

[picture of gap with inspect element shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEp9M.jpg)

Comment: Could you post the url so I could take a closer look?

Comment: Then maybe it's the `<img>` that has a top-padding or margin. Can't see it from your screenshot.

Comment: imrafaelhi the site is not live, you cannot access it.

Michael the img is classed as .welcome, it has no padding or margin as described in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Instead of using an img in this situation I used a div with the image as the background, no white space at all now. Thanks tho for everyone who replied.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job:

```
article p {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: This causes the entire image to disappear, anything I do that hides the p tag causes all of the content to disappear too, as the content is inside the p tag for some reason. I am thinking it must have something to do with the theme I'm using (blank html5 boilerplate theme) that places page content inside a p tag.